# Difference between IGBT and FET+BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt, igbt, fet

What are the practical differences between a true IGBT and a combination of FET and BJT, apart from a more efficient production and packaging? Can I obtain a device of comparable qualities to IGBT if I simply combine some (appropriately chosen) FET and BJT?

Comment: Draw a schematic so you can see the issues.

Comment: No, you can't. Would you make a BJT by connecting two opposing diodes considering the central terminal as the base?

Comment: It's not like Lego.

Comment: @Franc That would not work at all. Combining FET and BJT would work (basically a Darlington pair). My question is, how much different would it be from an IGBT.

Comment: yes you can, and you can customize each sub-component in that way too, like a logic-level fet, or a really high power BJT, p/n vs pnp/npn arrangements, gate source(emitter) resistors, Schottky flyback diodes, Schmitt trigger input, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a device like an "IGBT". Picture came from https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/igbt-transistor
The top PNP will need a B-E resistor to help turn it off faster.
[image]

Sziklai Darlington transistor is made from two transistors. [Sziklai Darlington](https://basicelectonicspalakpatel.blogspot.com/2014/08/darlington-transistor-pair.html)

[image]

Comment: The Darlington was previously built using two separate BJTs, then it was integrated. The SCR, however, cannot be done with two separate BJTs while the equivalent circuit can. Various equivalent circuits of the IGBT can be defined, the one shown is the most common but you cannot practically implement it with a MOSFET and a BJT.

Comment: @Franc I've made SCRs plenty of times; albeit for signal currents, as base current ratings are rarely very high. (A more accurate SCR would require doping levels that simply aren't commercially interesting, i.e. you could make a transistor with intentionally poor hFE and symmetrical Vebo/Vcbo, which would work well in a "discrete SCR" construction, or IGBT to some extent as well; but there's no reason to sell it alone, and all the more reason to sell the proper device-as-such.)

Comment: @Franc he's not asking about or answering to a question about SCRs